# Custom hook throw error from external package in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a custom hook:

```
const useMyHook = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  ...
  return state;
};
```

When I use this hook within the same project it's working fine:

```
const MyComp = () => {
  const state = useMyHook();
  ...
  return <ChildComp {...state} />
}
```

But when I export this hook from an external package (that I created):

```
import {useMyHook} from 'my-package';

const MyComp = () => {
  const state = useMyHook();
  ...
  return <ChildComp {...state} />
}
```

I get `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'dispatcher.useState')` with the following general error:

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

I want to assume that the problem is not the custom hook since it's working initially. I tought maybe it has to do something with versioning so in the external package I define the `package.json` with:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "18.1.0"
},
```

Same version as the `react` dependency in my original project in order to resolve react duplication as the error says.

Nothing of the solutions in the web works for me. Any idea what can cause this behavior?

FYI: I'm using `react-native` (with Expo).

Comment: Perhaps you need to define React inside the package files. I know that to serve jsx from the server React has to be defined so perhaps it is something similar.

Comment: @JosephWalker what does that mean?

Comment: in my serverside react files I have to include this in every file " import * as React from 'react' "

Comment: Share the code for my-package.

Comment: My guess is that you have mismatching versions of React
Share the package.json of both packages